# Force groupby values in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I sorted my dataset like this :

```
dt2<-dt[,list(Lconf=length(blockid)),by=list(subject,conf,state,memtype)]

   subject conf state memtype Lconf   conf_tx
1:   LT003    0    FA      FM    13 0.2031250
2:   LT003    0    FA      WM    21 0.3333333
3:   LT003    0    OM      FM    15 0.2343750
4:   LT003    0    OM      WM    16 0.2500000
5:   LT003    1    FA      FM    27 0.4218750
6:   LT003    1    FA      WM    27 0.4285714
```

with `conf_tx` a ratio calculated later. I want the mean for all subjects, so :

```
dtconf<-dt2[,list(conf_tx=mean(conf_tx,na.rm=T)),by=list(conf,state,memtype)]

   conf state memtype   conf_tx
1:    0    FA      FM 0.1715586
2:    0    FA      WM 0.3694943
3:    0    OM      FM 0.3218533
4:    0    OM      WM 0.4531198
5:    1    FA      FM 0.4855792
6:    1    FA      WM 0.4961775
```

There are 4 values possible for `conf` from 0 to 3.

My problem is : some subjects do not have any values for `conf=3` in certain conditions, which results in a wrong mean.

**Is it possible to force data.table to create a row**

```
subject conf state memtype Lconf   conf_tx
  LT005    3    OM      WM     0 0.0000000
```

**even if there is no value ?** Something like `,by=list(conf=c(0,1,2,3),state,memtype)`

Precisions : I calculate the rate of each confidence response (0, 1, 2, 3) for each subject, so my ratio is the number of each response over the sum of all responses. When a subject never answered "3", I want a row where data.table still calculates `length(conf==3)=0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate your mean values, then add the missing combinations using a cross join:

```
#example data
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = rep(1:3, each = 3), b = rep(1:3, 3), x = rnorm(9))
DT <- DT[c(1:4, 6:9)]

#cross join
DT[CJ(a = 1:3, b = 1:3), on = c("a", "b")]
#   a b          x
#1: 1 1 -2.5665330
#2: 1 2  0.6298771
#3: 1 3  0.6448454
#4: 2 1  0.9303104
#5: 2 2         NA
#6: 2 3 -1.9168810
#7: 3 1 -0.7579373
#8: 3 2 -0.6833026
#9: 3 3  2.6123457
```

Comment: I see what cross join does, it seems to work as I want to in your example, but it didn't work on my dataset. Can CJ take more than 2 arguments ? in my case `(conf=0:3,state=c("FA","OM"),memtype=c("FM","WM"))`

Or maybe it's because they are not numeric ?

Comment: `CJ(conf=0:3,state=c("FA","OM"),memtype=c("FM","WM"))` works just fine. And the join should work too if you specified `on` correctly.

Comment: Indeed I just needed to also precise "subject". It works perfectly, thanks a lot !